# Grouping by a column in R

Tags: r

I have the data in the following format :

```
 RouteId, StopOrder, StopType 
101, 1, Load 
101, 2, Unload
102, 1, Load
102, 2, Load
102, 3, Unload
102, 4, Unload
103, 1, Load
103, 2, Unload
103, 3, Load
103, 4, Unload
```

Given this data, I want to identify such routeIds which have a Load stop after unload stop.

```
Expected Output:
103
```

Comment: 103 is the expected output , as it is the only routeId which has Load after Unload.

Comment: Posted a possible solution.  Please check if that works for your original dataset.

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df2)`, grouped by 'RouteId', `if` `any` of the run-length-type id of the logical vector (`StopType=='Load')` is greater than 2, we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`).  This will give the rows with 'RouteId' 103.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[,if(any(rleid(StopType=='Load') >2)) .SD ,.(RouteId)]
#    RouteId StopOrder StopType
#1:     103         1     Load
#2:     103         2   Unload
#3:     103         3     Load
#4:     103         4   Unload
```

If we need only the 'RouteId', just extract it, by subsetting from the logical vector.

```
setDT(df2)[, .GRP[any(rleid(StopType=='Load') >2)] ,
   .(RouteId)]$RouteId
#[1] 103
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be

```
 v1 <-  with(df2, tapply(StopType=='Load', RouteId, 
             FUN= function(x) {i1 <- which(x)
                  i1>1 || any(diff(i1)>1)}))

 names(v1)[v1]
 #[1] "103"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. What is the significance of i1>1 ? Why cant we just have any(diff(i1)>1) ?

Comment: @Hima  It is just to take care of certain cases ..

Comment: Like what ? I mean I was wondering if it should have been "&&" instead of "||" .  I am very new to R. So, please bear with me. Wouldn't the function return true for every case where stop type is "Load" and has an index of  > "1" irrespective of whether there is an unload before it or not , since it is an OR condition ?

Comment: @Hima Suppose if the first element of 'StopType' is 'Unload' and the second is 'Load' (in this case there are only two elements for 'RouteId' 101)

Comment: @Hima I tried some combinations and the second solution worked on those.  Still, there may be some bugs.  If you can find some, will be happy to change the code.

Comment: ok, But Wouldn't the function return true for every case where stop type is "Load" and has an index of > "1" irrespective of whether there is an unload before it or not , since it is an OR condition ?

Comment: @Hima Have you tried it on that example?

Comment: Yes, I tried. And it was returning correct value . So, the code is definitely working as expected.  I am just trying to understand why the OR condition is not affecting the output

Comment: @Hima I am using `||`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible `dplyr` solution.  This is based on your comment that you expect `RouteId` values as output.

```
library(dplyr)

# assuming your data is loaded into "df"
(df %>%
    arrange(RouteId, StopOrder) %>%
    group_by(RouteId) %>%
    filter(StopType == 'Unload' & lead(StopType) == 'Load') %>%
    ungroup)$RouteId
```